# PostgreSQL: how to convert text date to show in the format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Tags: postgresql

I was taking an online exam on postgre SQL. The first step is about cleaning data and there is a column named 'date1' in the text datatype and has a format as: YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000.
The requirement is to convert it to date (data type) and show it in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.
The requirement is not to update the table, just query the table as the instruction.

What I did is:
SELECT CAST(date1 AS DATE) AS date1
FROM tablename

However, when the table is displayed, it still shows date1 column in the format as:
YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000
I thought once it's converted to date datatype, it should not show the time part anymore. Can someone help? Thank you very much!

Comment: `select cast('2024-01-02T14:28' AS date); 2024-01-02`, so you are doing something different. More information needed, **add as text update to question text**: 1) Postgres version. 2) Is Postgres the community version or some fork? 3) Show query with actual data,

Comment: Hello Adrian, Thanks for your comment. The database is itegrated in a notebook of a workspace for this online exam and can't be downloaded. Unfortunately, I don't know which postgre sql version it is. When I try your line, my output of this workspace shows: 2024-01-02T00:00:00.000

Comment: Also check the IDE you are running your query in. If you run it via the psql command line, it should display just the 10 characters. But some IDE's might default to displaying `date` type as a timestamp with the time zero'd out.

Comment: 1) Per previous request add the information as update to your question text, not in the comments. 2) Define 'notebook' and 'workspace'. 3) Show the actual code you are using in the notebook.

Comment: You can always get the Postgres version with the query: **select version();**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that uses the To_Char function if you were interested

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST('2024-01-02T14:28' AS DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Probably not going to solve the issue. My guess is the OP is at some point doing some variant of  this `select cast('2024-01-02T14:28' AS date)::timestamp; 2024-01-02 00:00:00`

Comment: Hello Joel, I typed your line on my online-exam workspace, it shows: 2024-01-02T00:00:00.000 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 16 you can use the function pg_input_is_valid() to check if the content is valid, to avoid errors when casting the content to the correct data type. And since a DATE only contains the year, month and day of the month, you will never end up with the minutes or seconds.

```
SELECT CAST(date1 AS DATE) AS date1
FROM tablename
WHERE pg_input_is_valid(date1, 'date');
```

If you do see a time in your result, that must be your SQL client that makes a mess of the result. That would be something you have to fix in your client, since the database is doing everything right.

Comment: Hello Frank, thanks for your explanation, it's the SQL client is making some mess.